# How to reset my vscode to use development local server to display on chrome

Tags: html

My project is not displaying images on the development Web server. How can I reset my vscode to default settings

Answer (score 1):

You can open user settings through the command palette:

1. Press  `F1`
2. Type `"user settings"`
3. Press `Enter`
4. Click the `"sheet"` icon to open the `[settings.json][1]` file:

[sheet icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DJJJ.png)

You can delete the contents and save them to reset your settings.